# Extract last element in a tuple with per category

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a tuple with the following output:

```
(State A, 0:07:58)
(State A, 0:15:48)
(State B, 0:32:20)
(State B, 1:04:30)
etc...
```

I am trying to isolate the last element times for each state and append them to a list.. so for the example above it would be `0:15:48` and `1:04:30` as they are the last times for the particular state.

I know how to get a last element in a list (`lst[-1]`) but with conditions involved I'm not so sure how to do it. I don't think I need to turn my tuple into a list as i'm not changing data, just trying to extract it.

Any help appreciated. Ideally without pandas.

Cheers

Comment: Can you clarify: do you need last time (by location in list), or *latest* time? If the latter, is your data sorted by State & Time?

Comment: Last time. Cheers

Comment: In addition, what exactly is the format of your input is it a list of tuples, a tuple of tuples, or something else?

Comment: It is a list of tuples

Comment: Hi arsenal, is the states already sorted..?

Comment: Yea. It is sorted already. Just need the last 'time' per state category. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, taking advantage of the fact that `dict` will overwrite a value with the last available instance of a key.

```
lst = [('State A', '0:07:58'),
       ('State A', '0:15:48'),
       ('State B', '0:32:20'),
       ('State B', '1:04:30')]

res = list(dict(lst).items())

# [('State A', '0:15:48'), ('State B', '1:04:30')]
```

Of course, `dict(lst)` is sufficient if you do not require a list of tuples as output.

You can expand on the idea if you have multiple values:

```
lst = [('State A', '0:07:58', 'X'),
       ('State A', '0:15:48', 'Y'),
       ('State B', '0:32:20', 'Z'),
       ('State B', '1:04:30', 'W')]

res = [(i,)+j for i, j in {k: tuple(v) for k, *v in lst}.items()]

# [('State A', '0:15:48', 'Y'), ('State B', '1:04:30', 'W')]
```

Comment: This seems the most ideal solution , however, what if my tuple contains 3 elements rather than 2 (key, value)?

Comment: I keep getting an error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for that. For instance you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([('State A', '0:07:58'), ('State A', '0:15:48'), ('State B', '0:32:20'), ('State B', '1:04:30')], columns=['state', 'time'])
df.groupby('state').agg('max')
```

it will return:

```
          time
state
State A  0:15:48
State B  1:04:30
```

Finally, you can easily store it in a csv, or put it as a list of tuples, ... The choice is yours :)

Comment: Thanks. I had that idea too but I'm trying to avoid using pandas as I don't want extra library dependencies

Comment: @arsenal88, yes but it has the advantage of keeping the max value, which might not be the last one every time , right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [("State A", "0:07:58"),
("State A", "0:15:48"),
("State B", "0:32:20"),
("State B", "1:04:30"),
("State B", "0:32:20"),]
print(dict(data))
>>> {'State A': '0:15:48', 'State B': '0:32:20'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pattern is the same all throughout in the list of tuples, you could try something like this:

```
l = [('State A', '0:07:58'), 
     ('State A', '0:15:48'), 
     ('State B', '0:32:20'), 
     ('State B', '1:04:30')]

output = [tupl[1] for n, tupl in enumerate(l) if n%2]
# ['0:15:48', '1:04:30']
```

Answer (score 0):

I may give an idea, isolating by the last element look similar with how `dict` works.

For example:

`x = ( ('a' , 11), ('a', 7177), ('b', -1717), ('c', 1828), ('b', -181881) )`

Changing this to dictionary

`dict(x)` will return

`{'a': 7177, 'c': 1828, 'b': -181881}`

Which saves the last element for each alphabet here.